# Possible to combine two Actions in c#?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm just playing around with `Action`s to extract the lambda expressions.

I have a boolean variable, and based on it's value, my lambda body should be different.

However, in this particular case, the difference is just calling another method which doesn't change the return type. This is what I have:

```
Action<MyType> myLambda;

if (myBooleanCondition)
{
     myLambda = x => x.ChangeBehavior();
}
else
{
     myLambda = x => x.ChangeBehavior().ChangeSize();
}
```

Is it possible to reduce/merge the two lambda definitions to one to make it more elegant?

This project uses C# 4.0, but if it's been simplified in the newer versions, please let me know.

Comment: What is wrong with that code? Also, can't you just make an `if` around the `ChangSize`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman -- Do you mean make it a multi-line lambda?  Or do you have a fluent way of doing it?

Comment: Are those extension methods btw?

Comment: The "ChangeBehavior()" and "ChangeSize()" functions are 4-line function calling monsters, and similar conditional redefinitions will be used multiple times in the project. Just to refactor and make the result "less-ugly".

Comment: You know your code doesn't compile, right? `x.ChangeBehavior().ChangeSize();` is not valid.

Comment: @Dennis_E -- why? `x.ChangeBehavior()` might return `x`.

Comment: Oh yeah. Because he's assigning it to an `Action<>` (which returns void), I didn't realize.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible to use the `+=` operator to concatenate delegates, which you can use to simplify your specific example.

For example, you could simplify your code like this:

```
Action<MyType> myLambda = x => x.ChangeBehavior();

if (!myBooleanCondition)
    myLambda += x => x.ChangeSize();
```

Full compilable example:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class MyType
    {
        public MyType ChangeBehavior()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ChangeBehavior()");
            return this;
        }

        public void ChangeSize()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ChangeSize()");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var x = new MyType();

            test(true)(x);       // Calls ChangeBehavior()
            Console.WriteLine();
            test(false)(x);      // Calls ChangeBehavior() and then ChangeSize()
        }

        static Action<MyType> test(bool myBooleanCondition)
        {
            Action<MyType> myLambda = x => x.ChangeBehavior();

            if (!myBooleanCondition)
                myLambda += x => x.ChangeSize();

            return myLambda;
        }
    }
}
```

Having said that, I don't think you should do it - it's too subtle. There's nothing wrong with your original code!

Comment: @GiladGreen I know the feeling. :)

Comment: should have posted it without testing XD

Comment: wow! I was thinking about something like that, but did not reach the end. But methiks this solution can be wrong if  _ChangeBehavior_ create new instance instead return same.

Answer (score 6):

Does exactly the same but might look to you ***more elegant*** (which is what the question is about): use the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (?:)

```
Action<MyType> myLambda = myBooleanCondition ? x => x.ChangeBehavior() :
                                               x => x.ChangeBehavior().ChangeSize();
```

Comment: Its the same thing

Comment: @PatrickHofman - true.... it has no real difference. but he is asking for a more elegant way... might be this..

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the same thing @GiladGreen.  Why does the OP need this anyway?

Comment: Don'tknow why downvotes... he want it to perform the same just in less lines: _Is it possible to reduce/merge the two lambda definitions to one to make it more elegant?_

Comment: @PatrickHofman, "Effectively the same" is precisely what the OP is looking for. The question is about elegance and not effectiveness.

Comment: At the end after all these downvotes the other answer is almost the same... maybe even less elegant..

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine.  But here are some alternatives.

This one creates a closure for the myBooleanCondition variable.

```
bool myBooleanCondition = false;

Action<MyType> myLambda = (x) => {
    if (myBooleanCondition)
    {
         x.ChangeBehavior();
    }
    else
    {
         x.ChangeBehavior().ChangeSize();
    }
};
```

This one allows you to pass in the boolean condition.

```
Action<MyType, bool> myLambda = (x, condition) => {
    if (condition)
    {
         x.ChangeBehavior();
    }
    else
    {
         x.ChangeBehavior().ChangeSize();
    }
};
```

This one creates a closure for both the myType variable and the myBooleanCondition variable.

```
bool myBooleanCondition = false;
MyType myType = new MyType();

Action myLambda = () => {
    if (myBooleanCondition)
    {
         myType.ChangeBehavior();
    }
    else
    {
         myType.ChangeBehavior().ChangeSize();
    }
};
```

The best choice for your code really depends on the use case.

Comment: Though will work these solutions are longer and might look less elegant than his original code

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `else` branch if use buffer variables, like this

```
Func<MyType, MyType> ChangeBehavior, func;
func = ChangeBehavior = x => x.ChangeBehavior();

if (!myBooleanCondition)
    func = x => ChangeBehavior(x).ChangeSize();

Action<MyType> myLambda = x => func(x);
```